# How to combine two line by matching the pattern in shell script

Tags: linux, scripting

I was trying to combine the two lines.
example of my data is ::

```
Hello Reach World Test
Reach me Test out .
```

I would like to combine this as ::

```
Output
Hello Reach World Test Reach me Test out  .i.e Only if last word matches Test and Begin matches Reach .
```

I was trying with 
awk '/Test$/ { printf("%s\t", $0); next } 1' .

Could anyone please let me know how to match it and combine.

Comment: To clarify, you are just trying to replace all occurrences of "Test\nReach" with "Test Reach", right?  Try: `perl -0777 -pe 's/Test\nReach/Test Reach/g;' input`

Comment: this may be a dup:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed

Comment: No , My input will be like Test  in next line reach ,I want to combine into single line using the matching pattern Test and Reach .

Answer (score 0):

Does this awk script do what you want:

```
BEGIN { flag = "0"; line = "" }
{
    if ( flag == "1" ) {
        if ( $0 ~ "^Reach" )
            print line " " $0
        else {
            print line
            print $0
        }
        line = ""
        flag = "0"
    } else {
        if ( $0 ~ "Test$" ) {
            line = $0
            flag = "1"
        } else
            print $0
    }
}
```